# JsPlumb: How to create new connection dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, connection, jsplumb

Here is a problem i've experienced with.

```
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var instance = initializeInstance(wrapperID);
        allConnections.push(instance.connect ( 
            { 
                source  : connectionsArray[j].source, 
                target  : connectionsArray[j].target
            }
        ));
        jsPlumb.fire(".some-selector", instance);
    }
```

So this is the way i'm saving all the connections on the page between the elements. User has the possibility to add dynamically new elements to the page ... he/she is doing it by dragging the mouse pointer from one element to another on the page ..... i dunno how to add newly created connection into my allConnections array.

```
   newInstance = initializeInstance(wrapperID);
   newInstance.bind('connection', function(info){
       //   TO DO: push to allConnections Array newly created connection
       //   allConnections.push(this.connect(info.sourceId, info.targetId)); - this line does'n work :(
   });
```

How to add newly created connection on UI to my allConnections array ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need your own array ?! You can always `query` jsPlumb to return all connections.

`jsPlumb.getAllConnections()` or `jsPlumb.select()`

Above will return a connection array. You can use it everywhere instead of using allConnections (array from the code in question)

Docs - http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/querying

Secondly, if you still want to add it to your array, then you can bind to events provided by jsPlumb. `connection` event is fired whenever a new connection is created.

Docs - http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/events#evt-connection

Thirdly, there is no need to create multiple instances of jsPlumb. You can simply use `jsPlumb.connect` or create a single instance of it & use it everywhere. Currently, the code uses `jsPlumb`, `instance` and `newInstance` and the last two being created every now & then.